# Probability problem with estimated value

Tags: probability

Let X be a geometric distribution with parameter $$p = \frac 19$$

i.e. $$P(X = k) = \frac {\frac{8}{9}^{( k−1)}}{9} $$

for k ∈ {1, 2, 3, . . .}

**What is the value of E(X)?**

I calculated that E[X] = 9, since the geometric distribution of an $E[X] = \frac 1p$

I understand this part.

**What is the value of P(X ≥ 5)?**

I am questioning myself on this one. From what I understand, the formula for this is:
$$P(X > a) < \frac{E[X]}{a}$$

However, when applied to the problem above, the answer to this would be 1.8, which is beyond 1.

I am looking for some clarification to this.

Comment: Your probability mass function is wrong; it should be $P(X = k) = (1 - p)^{k}p$ or $P(X = k) = (1 - p)^{k - 1}p$, depending on which definition of the geometric distribution you're using.

Comment: I think I missed the exponent. I edited my question

Comment: With the correct formula, you shouldn't have an inconsistency in the formula for $P(X \gt a)$; it'll produce a value in $[0, 1]$.

Comment: But how does the formula plays into this? the E[X] is just $\frac 1p$ which equals 9. So the first part of the formula should not influence the E[X] result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the support $k\in\{1,2,3,...\}$, the probability mass function is: (the probability of $k-1$ successive failures *then* $1$ success)

$$p_X(x) ~=~ (1-p)^{k-1}p$$

The expectation is as you had: $\mathsf E(X)=\frac 1 p$

The corresponding Cumulative Distribution Function is: (the probability of *not* having *all* failures in the first k trials)

$$\Pr(X\leq k) ~=~ 1-(1-p)^k$$

Comment: So the formula $$P(X > a)  < \frac{E[X]}{a}$$  has no use here, correct?

Comment: Ok. wrong formula. I understand now. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ be a positive integer. Then $\Pr(X\gt a)$ is the probability of $a$ consecutive "failures."

In our case this is $\left(\dfrac{8}{9}\right)^a$.

*Remark:* The formula $\Pr(X\gt a)=\frac{E[X]}{a}$ is not correct.